# Смена фокуса

Tags: javascript, php

Вот вопрос (понимаю глупый, но...): как установить фокус на нужный элемент (например на select) при нажатии кнопки?
Просто у меня при нажатии на кнопку, прячется половина элементов формы (так задумано), но очень неудобно то, что мы остаемся внизу страницы, а надо нам на середину.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дай своему селекту `id`, например `hashcode`
и

```
<button onclick="sample_click(this)"></button>
<script>
function sample_click() {
  var a = document.getElementById('hashcode')
  a.focus();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Первое: определяем высоту страницы - `screen.availHeight` .
Второе: определяем координату `y` элемента относительно верха страницы. Код можно взять, например, на [Координаты элемента на странице](http://javascript.ru/ui/offset) .
Третье: вычисляем `y` так, чтобы элемент оказался посередине окна.
Четвертое: скроллим страницу - `window.scroll(0, y);` .
Пятое (опционально): даем фокус на элемент - `_элемент_.focus()`;